# What functionality to build into business objects?

Tags: oop, persistence, business-objects

What functionality do you think should be built into a persistable business object at bare minimum?

For example:

- validation
- a way to compare to another object of the same type
- undo capability (the ability to roll-back changes)

Comment: Classes should have only one kind of functionality (single responsibility principle). Use multiple classes when you want to do multiple things.

Comment: Single responsibility doesn't necessarily mean that the class does just one thing.  If a Policy object can sensibly getQuote, rate, and issue, then there could be three different methods, each of which does one thing.  The three methods all relate to a Policy object.  I think the DDD answer below is the right view.

Comment: In a DDD sense, you will probably use validation in seperate objects for each validating context, you will implement rollback using a unit of work or memento, but it's fine to create the Policy object you describe including an equals method. Different things belong to different classes, but related thing should be together. Especially when using DDD, using different classes with different names can add value to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality dictated by the domain & business.

Read [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

Answer (score 1):

A persistable business object should consist of the following:

- Data
- New
- Save
- Delete
- Serialization
- Deserialization

Often, you'll abstract the functionality to retrieve them into a repository that supports:

- GetByID
- GetAll
- GetByXYZCriteria

You could also wrap this type of functionality into collection classes (e.g. BusinessObjectTypeCollection), however there's a lot of movement towards using the Repository Pattern in Domain Driven Design to provide these type of accessors (e.g. InvoicingRepository.GetAllCustomers, InvoicingRepository.GetAllInvoices).

You could put the business rules in the New, Save, Update, Delete ... but sometimes you could have an external business rules engine that you pass off the objects to.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one piece of an answer, but I would say that you need a way to get to all objects with which this object has a relationship. In the beginning you may try to be smart and only include one-way navigability for some relationships, but I have found that this is usually more trouble than it's worth.

All persistent frameworks also include finders, ways to do cascading deletes... sorts....

Once you start modeling, all business objects should know how to manage themselves. Whenever you find another class referring TO your business object too much, it's usually time to push that behavior into the business object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Of the three things noted in the question, I would say that validation is the only one that is truly required. The others depend on the overall archetecture of the application.

Also, the business rules should be in the business objects.

Whether an object should do its own serialization is an interesting question. I have had great success in the past by having each object handle its own serialization, but I can also see merit in having a serialization module load and save the business objects just the same way as the GUI writes to and reads from the objects. Then your validation will protect against errors in the database or files too.

I can't think of anything else that is required in general.